# "Show In Playlist" CatalinaOS

Tags: catalina, music, music.app

I've created a custom keyboard shortcut for the "Show In Playlist" command in the Music app. When I use the shortcut, I can see the menu bar is selected, but it does not open a menu showing the playlists. I am aware this is possible by right/cmd-clicking on a song in the library, but this is a tedious process for a large library. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would normally need a nested menu command `Show in Playlist->ListName` but this doesn't seem to work in the instance. It shows the key command in the right place but doesn't act on it.

[image]

I thought at one point that if you could find the correct symbol for the gear icon [image] then it might work, but best I can find is ⚙︎ which doesn't seem to have any effect. The key command appears to be correctly registered without it anyway.